# On Web 8.5, XPM's session preview doesn't work

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5

On our Web 8.5 instance, the XPM (Experience Manager) session preview doesn't work.

Sympthom is that, after clicking "Update Preview" button, content created on XPM doesn't appear and "The preview for this page is not up to date" message apprears instead.
Data is inserted into Session Preview DB successfully.

I installed and configured following modules.

- Session-enabled Content Service
- Preview Service
- Session Web site extension

In the Web site's debug log, following log is output.

> 2017-08-18 15:41:39,744 DEBUG PageContentFilter - No session has been started!
>
> 2017-08-18 15:41:39,744 DEBUG PageContentFilter - No session has been started!

Also I decompiled `PageContentFilter.class`, and found following code.

```
PreviewSession session = obtainPreviewSession();
if(session == null)
{
    LOG.debug("No session has been started!");
} else
{
```

It seems `obtainPreviewSession` method returning null causes problem.

What cases does `obtainPreviewSession` method to return null?

My web.xml is following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"

        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
        <display-name>website</display-name>
        <jsp-config>
                <taglib>
                        <taglib-uri>/cd_tags</taglib-uri>
                        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/content-tags.tld</taglib-location>
                </taglib>
        </jsp-config>
        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>/news_events/*</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>Ambient Client Filter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.sdl.web.ambient.client.AmbientClientFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>Ambient Client Filter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>PageContentFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.sdl.web.preview.client.filter.ClientPageContentFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>PageContentFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>BinaryContentFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.sdl.web.preview.client.filter.ClientBinaryContentFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>BinaryContentFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <filter>
                <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <error-page>
                <error-code>400</error-code>
                <location>/WEB-INF/error/400.html</location>
        </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Also there is following element in Session Web site extension's cd_client_conf.xml. What value does have to be set in `MachineName` and `FileLocation`?

```
<PreviewService MachineName="MachineName1" FileLocation="C:/temp" DefaultFileSystem="true"/>
```

`PreviewService` in `cd_client_conf.xml` seems to be required. If it's remove, following error occurs.

```
22-Aug-2017 08:25:56.961 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter PageContentFilter
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sdl.web.preview.client.session.MachineNameProvider.getMachineName(MachineNameProvider.java:20)
```

Comment: Have you configured ADF in your web.xml? Could you post that configuration?

Comment: Yes, I configured ADF in web.xml. I post it.

Comment: To find out if Experience Manager is set up properly, run the command java -jar discovery-registration.jar read and verify that PreviewWebServiceCapability and ContentServiceCapability are mentioned in the result.

Comment: also, ensure that your Preview Service running and port will be accessible on your web app server, enable logback.xml error level to debug to see if you are getting any errors anything in the cd_core.log

Comment: I confirm that PreviewWebServiceCapability and ContentServiceCapability have registered. I checked configuration, and I noticed there is an element what I cannot understand its value is correct or not. That is "PreviewService" element in Session Web site extension's cd_client_conf.xml. What value is have to be written in this element. I also update my question about that.

Comment: seems to look like you are using wrong configs, double check your cd_client_conf.xml config

Comment: it should look like this.
<ServiceConfig CacheEnabled="true"
               ConnectionTimeout="10000" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ServiceAvailabilityCheck="true"               CacheProviderClass="com.sdl.web.client.cache.GeneralCacheProvider"
               CacheConnectionTimeout="10000"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_client_conf.xsd">
    <DiscoveryService ServiceUri="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc"/>
    <TokenService ClientId="x" ClientSecret="x"/>
</ServiceConfig>

Comment: PreviewService element in cd_client_conf.xml seems to be required, because an error occurs if it's removed. Solution is enabling two elements in Session-enabled Content Service's cd_ambient_conf.xml.

Answer (score 2):

To make Session Preview work, enabling following two elements in `Session-enabled Content Service`'s `cd_ambient_conf.xml` is required. Those are commented out when the service is installed.

```
<GloballyAcceptedClaims>
    <Claim Uri="taf:session:preview:preview_session"/>
</GloballyAcceptedClaims>

<Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
```

Comment: Can you please mark this as the accepted answer?